# MLFlow - running "mlflow ui" throwing file not found error on windows 10

Tags: python, mlflow

I have done the training with sklearn model along with `mlflow` and it generated the `mlruns` folder.

When I try to run `mlflow ui` it throws the following error.

There is bug in Git https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/1670 but doesn't have any solution.
Have anyone faced and have any work around for this ?

Tried re-installation.

Attaching the traces below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Vivek.ananthan\Anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\Scripts\mlflow.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1668, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\site-packages\mlflow\cli.py", line 280, in ui
    _run_server(backend_store_uri, default_artifact_root, host, port, None, 1)
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\site-packages\mlflow\server\__init__.py", line 138, in _run_server
    exec_cmd(full_command, env=env_map, stream_output=True)
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\process.py", line 34, in exec_cmd
    child = subprocess.Popen(
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\vivek.ananthan\anaconda3\envs\deepcpu\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: have you tried mlflow ui --host 0.0.0.0?

Comment: I have the same issue. Also tried to specify the host as suggested above, the same issue occurred

Comment: Any update on this issue? Same behavior over here on Windows 10 with python 3.7

Comment: Did you run mlflow ui from the folder where mlruns is stored?
mlrunspath = "path/where/mlruns".
So open cmd or powershell, then cd "path/where/", and then run mlflow ui.

Comment: @Kaschi14 yes, same error